# undefined method 'name' in nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

So we are currently working on a website for an important customer, and we have run into a roadblock that has prevented further progression. We were working on relationships between database tables and one of the tables is not recognizing the above named method. Here is the code:

organizers_controller.rb:

```
  # GET /organizers.json
def index
  @organizers = Organizer.all
end

# GET /organizers/1
# GET /organizers/1.json
def show
end

# GET /organizers/new
def new
  @organizer = Organizer.new
end

# GET /organizers/1/edit
  def edit
end

# POST /organizers
# POST /organizers.json
def create
  @organizer = Organizer.new(organizer_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @organizer.save
    format.html { redirect_to @organizer, notice: 'Organizer was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @organizer }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @organizer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PATCH/PUT /organizers/1
# PATCH/PUT /organizers/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @organizer.update(organizer_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @organizer, notice: 'Organizer was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @organizer }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @organizer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /organizers/1
# DELETE /organizers/1.json
def destroy
  @organizer.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to organizers_url, notice: 'Organizer was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_organizer
    @organizer = Organizer.find(params[:id])
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def organizer_params
  params.require(:organizer).permit(:name)
end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @event.title %>
  <strong>Organization</strong>
  <%= @organizer.name %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(@event) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', events_path %>
```

Relevant error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Excuse the spacing issues, the code didn't translate well over to the codeblock

Comment: `@organizer` is nil, so you are getting this error.

Comment: Are you sure the error message is correct? I would rather expect "undefined method `title`", since you seem to have `@organizer` instance variable set, but the `@event` instance variable is unset.

Comment: From where you are getting @event.

Comment: Please, show where set_organizer is called. That can be the root of the problem. It should be at the top of the file

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out the `Organizer.title` line. See if you get other errors. It will get you on the right track. Also go into the console and mess around with the relationships. You didn't post the relationship so it's hard to know. Something like `event.organizer.name` could be nesseccary.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some conversation with colleagues, I have figured out the answer to my issue. Strangely enough, it was such a simple answer. I just needed to change <%= @organizer.name %> to:

```
<% @event.organizers.each do |organizer| %>
  <%= organizer.name %>
<% end %>
```

The fact that it was a many-to-many relationship and the fact that show did not have access to the @organizer variable. So this loop was necessary to display the correct info. Thanks for the responses anyways, glad you took the time!